# What are the OnPlatform Strings in Xaml(.Net Maui)

Tags: xaml, maui

I have a Maui app and want to style my app according to the platform I am on.
In a resource dictionary, I can use the following

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <OnPlatform x:Key="ButtonSize" x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
        <On Platform="iOS" Value="14" />
        <On Platform="Android" Value="16" />
    </OnPlatform>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

What are the "Platform Strings" for Windows and Mac?

```
<On Platform="???" Value="16" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/xaml/markup-extensions/consume#onplatform-markup-extension)

- Android
- iOS
- MacCatalyst
- Tizen
- WinUI